# New EDM-Rock Bands (Not old bands, Not metal, Not Djs)

Tags: rock, electronic-music, bands, alternative-rock, house

Can anyone suggest bands with this criteria?

- New bands (not bands with long careers like Depeche Mode, Nine Inch Nails, The Prodigy, etc)
- Electronic (EDM) and Rock at the same time.
- Not Metal bands
- Clean vocals (no screams)
- Not Djs. Band formation, not just remixes
- Guitars, keyboards, drums, etc.
- Similar to "The Maniac Agenda - Let it die" or "Celldweller - Frozen"
- Already know Pendulum and Innerpartysystem

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadouken, Does It Offend, You Yeah? and Modestep seem to fit the bill.
Wikipedia also lists these as similar to Hadouken:

> Associated acts   The Midnight Beast, Does It Offend You, Yeah?,
>   Pendulum, Noisia, Feed Me, Loadstar, Drumsound & Bassline Smith

Sources:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3r26y--evIw
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadouken!